# SAS token of azure container generated by c# client is not permitted to getAccessControl/setAccessControl

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, sas-token

I have a Spark application and I want to access an Azure Blob container by writing the event log into the blob container.

I want to authenticate using a SAS token. The SAS token generated by the Azure portal works fine. However, the one generated by the C# client does not work.  I dont know what's the difference between these two SAS token.

This is how I generate the SAS token in Azure portal

[image]

This is my spark conf

```
    spark.eventLog.dir: "abfss://sparkevent@lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net/log"
    spark.hadoop.fs.azure.account.auth.type.lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net: "SAS"
    spark.hadoop.fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net: ""
    spark.hadoop.fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net: "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider"
```

This is C# code:

```
            BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.HttpsAndHttp,
                BlobContainerName = "sparkevent",
                Resource = "b" // I also tried "c"
            };
            blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(BlobContainerSasPermissions.All);

            string sasToken2 = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(new StorageSharedKeyCredential("lydevstorage0", <access key>)).ToString();
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.", 403, HEAD, https://lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net/sparkevent/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&ti
meout=90&sv=2021-02-12&spr=https,http&st=2023-06-26T03:33:27Z&se=2023-06-28T03:33:27Z&sr=c&sp=racwdxlti&sig=XXXXX
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.checkException(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:1384)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:599)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.requireLogBaseDirAsDirectory(EventLogFileWriters.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.start(EventLogFileWriters.scala:221)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:612)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2704)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi$.main(SparkPi.scala:30)
        at org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi.main(SparkPi.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: Operation failed: "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.", 403, HEAD, https://lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net/sparkevent/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90&sv=2021-02-12&spr=https,http&st=2023-06-26T0
3:33:27Z&se=2023-06-28T03:33:27Z&sr=c&sp=racwdxlti&sig=XXXXX
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.completeExecute(AbfsRestOperation.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.lambda$execute$0(AbfsRestOperation.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.impl.IOStatisticsBinding.trackDurationOfInvocation(IOStatisticsBinding.java:464)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsRestOperation.execute(AbfsRestOperation.java:189)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:911)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.services.AbfsClient.getAclStatus(AbfsClient.java:892)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getIsNamespaceEnabled(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystemStore.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystemStore.java:932)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem.getFileStatus(AzureBlobFileSystem.java:609)
        ... 23 more
```

I tried the SAS token generated in Azure portal, it worked fine.

Comment: What is the `Resource = "b"` line? That isn't in your Portal screenshot.

Comment: How are you using your SAS token?

Comment: @Dai        Specify "b" if the shared resource is a blob. Specify "c"
I tried both, they do not work.. The portal screenshot shows the options of creating  SAS token for a blob container.

Comment: @GauravMantri I put the SAS in the hadoop conf, a SAS toekn provider will pass the SAS token to hadoop FS.

Comment: Are you trying to read blobs from `log` blob container using this token?

Comment: @GauravMantri I think it's block blob container, but I'm not sure how to verify.

Comment: Hi @mifan Are you using datalakegen2 account or normal v2 storage account?

Comment: Hi @Venkatesan, the account type is   ```StorageV2 (general purpose v2)```

Comment: Have you created the storage account with hierarchical namespace?

Comment: @Venkatesan yes, Hierarchical namespace is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **`Data-lake-gen2 account`** with a hierarchical namespace, you can use the [Datalake](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/) package with the below code to create a SAS token using C#.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;
using Azure.Storage.Sas;

namespace SAStoken
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var AccountName = "venkat098";
            var AccountKey = "";
            var FileSystemName = "filesystem1";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential key = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(AccountName, AccountKey);
            string dfsUri = "https://" + AccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";
            var dataLakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), key);
            var directoryclient = dataLakeServiceClient.GetFileSystemClient(FileSystemName);
            DataLakeSasBuilder sas = new DataLakeSasBuilder()
            {
                FileSystemName = FileSystemName,//container name
                Resource = "d",
                IsDirectory = true,
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                Protocol = SasProtocol.HttpsAndHttp,
            };
            sas.SetPermissions(DataLakeAccountSasPermissions.All);
            Uri sasUri = directoryclient.GenerateSasUri(sas);
            Console.WriteLine(sasUri);
        }

    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
https://venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystem1?sv=2022-11-02&spr=https,http&se=2023-07-04T05%3A53%3A39Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxxx
```

[image]

I checked the URL with the image file it working successfully.

```
https://venkat098.dfs.core.windows.net/filesystem1/cell_division.jpeg?sv=2022-11-02&spr=https,http&se=2023-07-04T05%3A53%3A39Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxx
```

**Browser:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Use .NET to manage data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet#create-a-service-sas-for-a-directory)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Venkatesan. But I still get such error ```https://lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net/sparkevent/log/spark-738c5488436d4a71a0b8957677ff177b.inprogress?action=setAccessControl&timeout=90&s
v=2022-11-02&spr=https,http&se=2023-07-04T06:40:28Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=XXXXX, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:093e86a5-c01f-0048-48c2-a8ecfc000000 Time:2023-06-27T06:41:35.3197275Z"```

Comment: Seems this SAS don't have the permission to perform *setAccessControl*

Comment: Check the network setting once it is in **`Enabled from all networks`**.

Comment: It's already set to ```Enabled from all networks```. And the SAS token I generated in Portal does not has such error.

Comment: I think your Url should be   `https://lydevstorage0.dfs.core.windows.net/sparkevent/log/something.txt?sv=2022-11-02&spr=https,http&se=2023-07-04T05%3A53%3A39Z&sr=c&sp=racwdl&sig=xxxxxxx` to access the file.

Comment: I am able to access the file, but the link above is not generated manually by myself, the error is from spark internal. What spark do is to create the file ```spark-738c5488436d4a71a0b8957677ff177b.inprogress```, put event logs into it. And according to the link in the error message, Spark also do "setAcessControl", which failed because the permission is not granted by the SAS token.

Comment: Thanks @Venkatesan ! after changing the permission set to DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions, it works!

Comment: @Venkatesan, sure, I have accepted your answer, and please slightly modified it by changing the permission set to DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions, this can avoid confusing peaple encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that my Spark program cannot get or set AccessControl.
I should not have used BlobSasToken or AccountSasBuilder because the blob container itself is not aware of what ACL is. Therefore, the SAS tokens generated by them naturally do not have ACL manipulation permissions.

With the help of @Venkatesan, I learned that I can also use [DataLakeSasBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.datalakesasbuilder?view=azure-dotnet). DataLake follows the HDFS standard, so it is aware of what ACL is. However, the permission set used by @Venkatesan is [DataLakeAccountSasPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.datalakeaccountsaspermissions?view=azure-dotnet), which does not include ManageAccessControl permission. The correct permission set is [DataLakeFileSystemSasPermissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.sas.datalakefilesystemsaspermissions?view=azure-dotnet). After switching to this permission set, my program can work properly.